# Complex Integral final steps

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration, cauchy-principal-value

How do we evaluate the Cauchy Principal value for:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos kx}{x-a}dx  $$

Given, a is real, k >${\ 0}$?

I thought of integrating from ${-\infty}$ to ${\ a}$ and then from ${\ a}$ to ${+\infty}$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take the function on the first row, multiply by $z-5$, substitute $z=5$

Comment: You shall check and correct your maths. I did it for you, by the way. But you cannot write similar malarkey.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\mbox{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{3x} \over x^{2} - 25}\,\dd x =
\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{3x} \over x^{2} - \pars{25 + \ic 0^{+}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{3x} \over
\pars{x + \root{25 + \ic 0^{+}}}\pars{x - \root{25 + \ic 0^{+}}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{3\ic x} \over
\pars{x + 5 + \ic 0^{+}}\pars{x - 5 - \ic 0^{+}}}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{-3\ic x} \over
\pars{x + 5 + \ic 0^{+}}\pars{x - 5 - \ic 0^{+}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\pars{2\pi\ic\,{\expo{3\ic\bracks{5 + \ic 0^{+}}} \over 10 + \ic 0^{+}}} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\pars{-2\pi\ic\,{\expo{-3\ic\bracks{-5 - \ic 0^{+}}} \over -10 - \ic 0^{+}}} =
{1 \over 10}\,\pi\,\bracks{\Re\pars{\ic\expo{15\,\ic}} +
\Re\pars{\ic\expo{15\,\ic}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{-\,{1 \over 5}\,\pi\sin\pars{15}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First note that the integral of interest $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{x^2-25}\,dx$ diverges.  Its Cauchy principal value ("CVP") does exist.  We will now present an approach to evaluate the CVP.

---

To apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem correctly we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C\frac{e^{i3z}}{z^2-25}\,dz&=\int_{-R}^{-5-\epsilon} \frac{e^{i3x}}{x^2-25}\,dx+\int_{-5+\epsilon}^{5-\epsilon} \frac{e^{i3x}}{x^2-25}\,dx+\int_{5+\epsilon}^{R} \frac{e^{i3x}}{x^2-25}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_{\pi}^{0} \frac{e^{i3(-5+\epsilon e^{i\phi})}}{(-5+\epsilon e^{i\phi})^2-25}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_{\pi}^{0} \frac{e^{i3(5+\epsilon e^{i\phi})}}{(5+\epsilon e^{i\phi})^2-25}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{i3Re^{i\phi}}}{(Re^{i\phi})^2-25}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag 1\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$, it is easy to see that the last integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$.  And as $\epsilon \to 0$, the fourth and fifth integrals approach $i(\pi/10) e^{-i15}$ and $-i(\pi/10)e^{i15}$, respectively.

Hence, letting $R\to \infty$ an d$\epsilon\to 0$, and taking the real part of $(1)$, we find that

> $$\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{x^2-25}\,dx\right)=-\frac{\pi \sin(15)}{5}$$

where

$$\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{x^2-25}\,dx\right)=\lim_{R\to \infty}\left(\int_{-R}^{-5-\epsilon} \frac{e^{i3x}}{x^2-25}\,dx+\int_{-5+\epsilon}^{5-\epsilon} \frac{e^{i3x}}{x^2-25}\,dx+\int_{5+\epsilon}^{R} \frac{e^{i3x}}{x^2-25}\,dx\right)$$

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes, there sure was.  I've edited it.  Thank you my friend.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful, I am happy to delete it. -Mark